# Open multiple files in a same UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have multiple buttons in `Main.storyboard`, and I want to add a text file to each button.
The problem is that I have to create a `UIViewController` for each button to make it work, but i want to open all files in one `UIViewController`.

For example:

```swift
@IBAction func btn_txt1(_ sender: Any) {
    txt_view.text = txt1.txt
}

@IBAction func btn_txt2(_ sender: Any) {
    txt_view.text = txt2.txt
}

@IBAction func btn_txt3(_ sender: Any) {
    txt_view.text = txt3.txt
}
```

How can I make this possible?
I am new to Xcode and Swift.

Comment: You need to add more detail to your code. "i have to create ViewController for each button" is not a clear statement.

Comment: Let's take a wild stab in the dark here... Do you mean: `txt_view.text = [txt1.txt, txt2.txt, txt3.txt].joined(separator: "\n\n")`?